# Parse.com discern update or insert in BeforeSave

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, before-save

I'm overriding the `BeforeSave` in `CloudCode` for `Parse.com`.
This is what I see in the `logs`:

```
Input: {"original":null,"update":{"password":"5428","phone_number":"56858","ACL":{"T1pXElsPPT":{"read":true,"write":true}},"config":"{}","creator":"T1pXElsPPT","name":"quarta prova"}}
Result: Update changed to {"config":"{}","creator":"T1pXElsPPT","name":"quarta prova","password":"5428","phone_number":"56858","ACL":{"T1pXElsPPT":{"read":true,"write":true}}}
```

I need to check the `BeforeSave` only if the user is creating a `new` object, not when he's `updating` an `old` one. This is what I've done so far:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("tracker", function(request, response) {
var spaces = availableSpace(request.user.id);
if (request.original != undefined && request.original === null) {
    if (spaces == 0) {
        response.error("No available spaces");
    } else if (spaces >= 1) {
        response.success();
    } else if (spaces < 0) {
        response.error("Lookup error");
    }
} else {
    response.success();
}
```

});

But it seems that `original` is not in the request object (so it's undefined, always leading to a `response.success();`)

Is there a way to check for `original` or another way to check if this is an `insert` or an `update`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Parse.Object.isNew()](http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#isNew)

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("tracker", function(request, response) {
  var spaces = availableSpace(request.user.id);
  if (request.object.isNew()) {

    if (spaces === 0) {
        response.error("No available spaces");
    } else if (spaces >= 1) {
        response.success();
    } else if (spaces < 0) {
        response.error("Lookup error");
    }

  } else {
      response.success();
  }
});
```